# How to enable my Joomla extension?

Tags: joomla

When logged in as Administrator and trying to install a [Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) extension it fails giving this error message

```
JFolder::create: 
Unable to create destination
```

At another Joomla site it works, and one difference is where it works Joomla is setup with default English and where it fails setup is in Swedish. Can you recommend how to troubleshoot and proceed? I tried with 2 different extensions and both work on the English joomla and not the Swedish.

Comment: could be a problem with file/directory permission on the language directories? maybe joomla is unable to save the swedish translations on the server or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to check the rwx (Read-Write-Execute) permissions (should be 644 or 755) for allowing the extension's folder to be created.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for where I do this since only having access to the joomla admin ui and no direct filesystem access.

Comment: Web hosting providers usually provide you with a backend UI, where you could find something like a "File Manager". That's the place where you can change the file/folder permissions. If you really have no access, contact with your administrator. I'm not aware if there is a way to change permissions via joomla admin ui

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the owner of the folders/files to the user of the Apache server using the "chown" command.

If the Apache user is `httpd`, run this command in your Joomla folder

```
chown -R httpd *
```

I already get this problem and this solution worked for me.

Also check the path to the `/tmp` folder in your `configuration.php` file.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I got FTP access via MS-Windows trying to see which folder it's trying to create. The PHP log could provide more information exactly where joomla fails to write.